# How can I move one Ubuntu installation to another?

Tags: boot, usb-drive

Here's what I'm asking in more detail:

Let's say I have Ubuntu installed on a flash disk, and I have another Ubuntu installation installed on an external HDD (both have the same Ubuntu version).

If I copy all the files in the root directory of the flash disk and use them to replace all the files in the root directory of the HDD, would it basically be the exact same as the flash disk (as in retaining the same settings, preferences, wallpapers, files, and programs) and boot just fine?

Comment: I think if you have the same version, it should work. The problem might be grub, /etc/fstab, etc.. Leave the grub files and /etc/fstab of the original installation. Don't overwrite them.

Comment: @nobody So as long as I don't overwrite that specific folder, everything should be fine?

Comment: I checked the root directory and there are also /boot, /dev, /media, /mnt, /proc. Copying /boot, /media and /mnt should not cause any problems but I would not copy them. I would definitely not recommend copying /dev and /proc. So now we have: grub files (/etc/default/grub, /etc/grub.d/), /boot, /dev, /media, /mnt, /proc. I am not sure what you want to accomplish but in general you should also be ok with copying only /home.

Comment: You want to overwrite the entire internal disk? I would get clonezilla, boot into that live system and clone the external HDD to the internal one (overwrites all data!). Then boot an Ubuntu live system (or the external HDD) and reinstall GRUB to the internal HDD. It should work, especially if the external HDD's system already ran on the machine and knows its graphics and other hardware.